# Lookup field load all items

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am having one SharePoint custom list. it is having 2 lookup fields. we are using SPservices.cascading drop down to filter second drop down by first drop down.
each lookup list is having around 4000 items.

Problem is there when i open new form of list it takes time to load because it loads all items from lookup list.

Can we somehow stop this behavior and load  no data in second lookup field when new form load first time?

Comment: Fill another dropdown on changing of first one and so on...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2pza5/